# iOS Build Issue due to paytm all in one sdk libary

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, paytm

Please Help when I create iOS Build But facing some issue "[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: **appinvokesdk.xcframework**."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.